# Submenu hides on hover

Tags: html, css, menu

I have HTML Menu and Submenu. For some reason, the submenu hides when I' am hovering over them. When I hover on the parent menu, submenu shows and as soon as am hovering over the submenu it hides.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">Home<span class="sf-sub-indicator"><i class="icon-angle-down"></i></span><span class="sub">Start here</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">Features<span class="sf-sub-indicator"><i class="icon-angle-down"></i></span><span class="sub">remix all features</span></a>
      <ul class="transparency">
        <li><a href="#">Accordion</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">Typography</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">MP3<span class="sub">full archive</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Video<span class="sub">latest clips</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">Gallery<span class="sf-sub-indicator"><i class="icon-angle-down"></i></span><span class="sub">Photo Gallery</span></a>
      <ul class="transparency">
        <li><a href="#">Gallery 4 Column</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery 3 Column</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery 2 Column</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Pages<span class="sf-sub-indicator"><i class="icon-angle-down"></i></span><span class="sub">more templates</span></a>
      <ul class="transparency">
        <li><a href="#">RTL Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MP3 Single Wide</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog<span class="sf-sub-indicator"><i class="icon-angle-down"></i></span><span class="sub">latest news</span></a>
      <ul class="transparency">
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog Left Sidebar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog Both Sidebar</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-menu{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 0 0 -20px;
}
#main-menu ul{
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#main-menu li{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}
#main-menu a{
    padding:0 20px 22px 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#main-menu li a span {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    display: block;
    color: #AFAFAF;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
#main-menu li ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 170px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
#main-menu li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 11px;
}
#main-menu li > ul li{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
#main-menu li > ul li a:hover{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}
#main-menu li > ul li a{
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8hVWz/4/)**

Just replace the `margin-top` by `padding-top` in this CSS:

```
#main-menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 11px;
}
```

So that it becomes:

```
#main-menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 11px;
}
```

**Proof**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can update the

```
#main-menu li ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width: 170px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

and

```
#main-menu li > ul li a{
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

further alignments u cand update as u want

Answer (score 1):

Change `margin-top` to `padding-top`, like so:

```
#main-menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 11px;
}
```